# Extract data string from an array and assign them to a variable by concatenation in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, variables, concatenation, inputbox, arrayobject

I have an array of objects like:

```
$arrayServ = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList(,$serv)
```

this array contains some objects like:

```
name        prefix                     tenants                  
----        ------                     -------                  
TOTO        http://home/toto           bob, michael, ramy, anna
Nav         http://8.8.8.8/google      com, uk, fr
```

I'm trying to Extract all data in the property `name` and put them in a variable and concatenate this variable with another variable which is a counter of the `name`.

Something like this:

```
$liste = "$i. $arrayServ [$i]"
```

Why I want do that ? It's because, I want to display that `$liste` in an InputBox, like:

```
$liste = "$i. $arrayServ [$i]"
$msg = $liste -join "`n"
$item = InputBox $msg -title "Your choice"
```

The InputBox "Your choice"

[image]

Does someone know how can I do that please ?

Comment: when you add to the arraylist, what is in it? the `,$Serv` is usually an _array_ notation that would put an array into the arraylist _as an array_ instead of as a series of objects. so ... what do you get from `$arrayServ[0].GetType()` and then from `$arrayServ[1].GetType()`?

Comment: As an aside: Please avoid pseudo method syntax: instead of `New-Object SomeType(arg1, ...)`, use `New-Object SomeType [-ArgumentList] arg1, ...` - PowerShell cmdlets and functions are invoked like _shell commands_ (no parentheses, whitespace-separated arguments), not like _methods_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you already have an array of objects in `$serv`, so there should be no reason to put this in an ArrayList..

If that is the case, you could create the `$liste` array like this:

```
$liste = @()
$i = 1
$serv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name | ForEach-Object {
    $liste += "{0}. {1}" -f $i++, $_
}
```

and then use it for the inputbox message using

```
$msg = $liste -join [Environment]::NewLine
```

Using your examples, this would return

> ```
> 1. TOTO
> 2. Nav
> ```

Putting this in an inputbox:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.VisualBasic'
$item = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msg, "Votre choix")
```

[image]

Comment: Nicely done. In PSv4+ you can shorten to `$arrayServ.name.ForEach({ '{0}. {1}' -f $i++, $_ })`

Comment: thanks a lot. It's exactly what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put all of the names into a variable, you can use `indexOf(value)` in your concatenation:

```
$arrayServ = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList(,$serv)
```

So create an array of just the names:

```
$names = $arrayServ.name
```

Based on the example data provided, if you knew you wanted to display the second item from that list, get the index value of 'Nav' and add 1 since the first index of an array is 0 and you want the count, not the index position:

```
$count = $names.indexOf('Nav') + 1
```

Set `$liste` to the count, then interpolate the item at the position of `$names` minus 1 from `$count` so you get the correct value.

```
$liste = "$count. $($names[$count - 1])"
```

This should display

```
2. Nav
```

Comment: I don't think the OP needs any _lookup_ of the array elements - just _enumeration_ with a sequence number.
As an aside, re the `New-Object` call: I know you only copied the OP's code, but given that this anti-pattern is so widespread, it's worth either quoting a fixed version or calling out the problem: Please avoid pseudo method syntax: instead of `New-Object SomeType(arg1, ...)`, use `New-Object SomeType [-ArgumentList] arg1, ...` - PowerShell cmdlets and functions are invoked like _shell commands_ (no parentheses, whitespace-separated arguments), not like _methods_.